# How to Query Which Table Is Inserted Mostly In SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have a database and there is not any trigger which follows the transactions in said database.

Now, I have to make a report that shows which table has mostly inserted so far. How can I do that?

Comment: As I understand you simply retrieve number of records in a table which equals number of inserts.

Comment: Approximate insertion count can be obtained by: checking records count increase (if no deletions), checking autoincrement (if exists) value increase.

Comment: @RajeshRanjan We can say it like that. I want to produce an report which tells us most inserted table between two certain dates.

Comment: @akina Is this approach true for everytime? Cause, there are different tables which doesn't include any identity column.

Comment: No identity - its checking not applicable. *Is this approach true for everytime?* No of course.

Comment: *I want to produce an report which tells us most inserted table between two certain dates* For each table in interest - create AFTER INSERT trigger which stores current date, table name and inserted records amount in some service table. PS. This service table may occur the most insertable :)

Comment: if you are using SQL Server 2016 there is feature called temporal table which track every transaction in a history table. Using that will help you to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Using this you can find out number of INSERTS, DELETE and UPDATES on a table.

Comment: @RajeshRanjan Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know mostly inserted table you can simply retrieve number of rows/records in the table.

You can use following query to find it. Mostly inserted tables will be displayed on top of the records.

```
SELECT
   o.Name TableName,SUM(ps.row_count) Total_Rows
FROM
            sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
inner join  sys.objects o
on ps.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE o.type='U'
GROUP BY
    o.Name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

**Edit:1**

As you described you requirement in comments, "you need find mostly inserted tables between a date range. It can be done using several method.

1. Using AFTER TRIGGER on the tables.
2. Using IDENTITY type column along with a column which records insert date & time (like Amina commented).
3. Using CDC you can record date & time of every changes in the table.
4. enabling **Temporal Table** (SQL Server 2016 +) feature on a table to record every changes.
5. Track Data Changes (SQL Server 2017)

Thanks!